# Преобразование списка объектов в массив байтов

Tags: java

В общем, пытаюсь конвертировать ArrayList в byte[].
Превратить его в массив байтов получается, но прочитать его обратно уже нет. В строке `in.available()` получаю 0, т.е. получаеться  `inputStream` пустой. Ниже приведу код:

```
private void invoke() {
    ArrayList<UObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new UObject(1,"name", "url11",null));
    list.add(new UObject(23,"second name", "url333",null));
    list.add(new UObject(4523,"third name", "url4453",null));
    list.add(new UObject(4523,"thgdfsgsdird name", "url4453",null));

    try {
        byte[] bytes = writeToByteArray(list);
        readToByteArray(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// write to byte array
private byte[] writeToByteArray(ArrayList<UObject> list) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    for (UObject element : list) {
        out.writeObject(element);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

 // read from byte array
private void readByteArray(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
   while (in.available() > 0) {
       UObject object = (UObject) in.readObject();
       Log.d(TAG, object.toString());
   }
}
```

**UDT:**

немного изменил тело метода:

```
private void readFromByteArray(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   while (bais.available() > 0) {
       ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
       UObject object = (UObject) in.readObject();
       Log.wtf(TAG, object.toString());
   }
}
```

и влогах вижу только первые элемент после чего падает с ошибкой:

```
UObject{id=1, name='name', avatarUrl='url11', progresses=null}

08-24 15:42:50.776 23872-24098/com.my.app W/System.err: java.io.StreamCorruptedException
```

Падает в строке:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
```

Comment: `ArrayList` ведь реализует интерфейс `Serializable`, почему не написать просто `out.writeObject(list)` ?

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: Я об этом почему то не подумал, все заработало. Можете оформить ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` ведь реализует интерфейс `Serializable`, напишите просто:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
out.writeObject(list);
```

и не забывайте использовать `close` для `Input/OutputStream`